# Hyperledger Fabric v1.3 - Consensus

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a technical doubt related to the HL Fabric consensus.

Does anyone know which is the current consensus algorithm implemented in v1.3? Can you describe it?

Where I can find more documentation about this topic?

Comment: for a consensus roadmap also see this, they are implementing raft.  https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-6135?jql=labels%20%3D%20raft - "It allows us to have an ordering service without Kafka/ZK depedencies, and It helps with the BFT development as well, since it gives us a chance to hook into Fabric a leader-based consensus protocol and carry those lessons over when writing the BFT plugin."

Comment: maybe have a look to this one too https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.00554.pdf where it starts with "Hyperledger Fabric implements a pluggable
consensus on the order of transactions in the..."

Answer (score 1):

Consensus can be broken into three phases in fabric from v1.0

- Endorsment Policy - For a transaction to be valid, it has to be
  endorsed by respective participants. This phase is even before going
  to orderer service.
- Ordering - Order the transaction in chronological order
- Validation(Commiting peer) - Validate the correctness of state
  (Comparison between the transaction state and world state)

A more detail read can be found here https://www.skcript.com/svr/consensus-hyperledger-fabric/